# Why don't textbooks on statistics start with an introduction to probability?

Tags: references, teaching

I recently read through [Introduction to Probability, Statistics, and Random Processes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0990637204) by Hossein Pishro-Nik (free online version available [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/)), and what I liked most about it is that it starts off explaining the fundamentals of probability, including set theory and sample spaces. The author then goes on to explain discrete and continuous random variables.

In comparison, [Statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8130915871) by Freedman et al. and [Statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119386055) by Witte et al. start discussing probability on pages 221 and 147 respectively.

In high school, I learned about probability and statistics using the latter approach, which made me dislike the area altogether because a lot of the reasoning felt informal with no theoretical basis. For example, I was taught that to compute the probability of something occurring, such as the probability of 6 heads occurring after 10 coin flips, I should divide the number of heads (6) by the number of total coin flips (10). However, this implicitly assumes that the coin is fair with a 50% probability of heads or tails. This implicit assumption also occurs when computing the probability of rolling a certain number on a die. It is implicitly assumed that all events are equally likely, but that is not necessarily true.

Alternatively, in probability theory, this probability can be computed using the three probability axioms, which I personally think provides a more satisfactory and formal answer than just dividing the number of possible times something occurs by the total number of experiments.

One of the biggest downsides of taking the "statistics" first approach is that it does not discuss the fact that all estimators are random variables with associated probability distributions. This gives some foundation for the bias-variance dilemma, since a bias and a variance only exist for random variables.

To summarize, the approach taken by statistics textbooks perpetuates the "cookbook" approach that I learned in high school, and I want to know why that is.

Comment: Short answer: statistics is not a branch of mathematics and should not be confused with the mathematical parts of its theory.

Comment: Building on what @whuber wrote, it would be the same as why a physics book doesn't start out with algebra and calculus.

Comment: That is very interesting. If statistics is not a branch of mathematics, then how is it formalized?

Comment: Your example is fallacious. If I count the fraction of times a thumb-tack falls one way rather than another  I am not assuming implicitly or explicitly that the two possibilities are equally frequent. But to the major point: this is largely market-driven. Far more people want or need to know statistics as methods for handling data than want or need to know first about a formal basis in probability theory.

Comment: @NickCox but if I had some prior belief that it is more likely to fall one way more than the other, how can I incorporate this belief without using the mathematical formalism introduced by probability theory?

Comment: Sure, you need formalism to do that. But that doesn't mean that pedagogy is driven that way. Otherwise we'd start kindergarten with Bourbaki books.

Comment: @NickCox Fair enough. So do you think the "cookbook" approach introduced in high-school is the best approach, or is there a better alternative?

Comment: If a group of students told  me "Please start with probability" I would be delighted to try. Hasn't happened yet (although I am a university geographer, so that shades the odds).

Comment: The first book I ever bought about statistics was aimed at the general reader and starting on page 4 the second chapter is entitled the laws of chance (_Facts from figures_ by Moroney) so your experience is not universal. Mind you it was written around 1950 when assuming a knowledge of set theory in the average UK reader with an interest in statistics would have been a stretch.

Comment: For a more picturesque version of whuber's comment, see the Preface of David Willams' _Weighing the Odds: A Course in Probability and Statistics,_  the first sentence of which reads "Probability and Statistics used to be married; then they separated; then they divorced; now they hardly ever see each other.

Comment: Don’t they? Many do.

Comment: Many so-called mathematical statistics texts at upper division and graduate level do start with probability: Wackerly, Mendenhall, Scheaffer Ch 2-6 out of 15 almost completely probability; Bain, Englehardt Ch 1-7 out of 16; also Mood, Graybill, Boes. But applied stat books have tended to start with descriptive statistics before brief mentions of binomial, normal, t, as needed for basic tests, ANOVA, regression (e.g., Daniel's _Biostatistics_ // Amer Math Soc considers statistics and CS as 'mathematical sciences'. Otherwise, their annual reports on jobs/salaries would have little to say.

Comment: @mhdadk: A data-driven approach do not need to be "cookbook". It becomes so *if* you start with a mathstat approach and just *water it down*.

Comment: Why doesn't your question start with some *statistics* about how often a statistics textbook doesn't start with mathematics?